# Get only Taxonomy from $content array

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, taxonomy-terms

I need to get the taxonomy from the `$content` array to print in the node template.  How can I do it? I tried with $`content['taxonomy']`. Where can I get a guide with all params in `$content` array?

Comment: what version of Drupal do you use?

Comment: Hi. Drupal 7...

Comment: print render($content['field_my_term_field'] should work

Answer (score 0):

`$content` contains the renderable elements of your node (see documentation on [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7)). This contains the node body, links, and other custom fields you've added to your node type. As Andrew suggested, the [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) function can print individual fields or all fields (`render($content)`).